# SQL cast a string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have to get horsepower field in database as integer but it contain value like below

```
330hp/@6,000
30hp/@3,000
1000hp/@6,000
```

Can Anyone suggest how can I cast this into integer?

I only need

```
330
30
1000
```

--
Cheers

Comment: Use CHARINDEX in combination with SUBSTRING/LEFT function.

Comment: Storing numeric data as a string always causes problems. In this case its even worse, since there are two pieces of data in there. Ideally, split that column into two - one that has the hp, and one that has the peak RPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select LEFT(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('h',ColumnName) - 1)
```

Read more [LEFT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177601.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This will work. If there is no 'h' in the text, it will return blank. If you want to cast, go ahead. But make sure you data is validated first.

Starting from 0 is a nice trick to remove the first character 'h' instead of subtracting 1 which would give errors when no 'h' exists

```
DECLARE @t table(col varchar(20))
insert @t values
('330hp/@6,000'),
('30hp/@3,000'),
('1000hp/@6,000'),
('123')

SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(col, 0, CHARINDEX('h', col))
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
330
30
1000
blank
```

Answer (score 2):

The below will work.

SELECT LEFT(@Test,PATINDEX('%hp/@%',@Test)-1)

Then cast the result as an int. You will want to put something like this in a try block for scenarios where you have bad data that doesn't fit the standard given.

SELECT CAST(LEFT(@Test,PATINDEX('%hp/@%',@Test)-1) AS INT)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

SELECT LEFT(col1, PATINDEX('%hp%', Col1) - 1)
FROM   MyTable